photoshop-python-api says that I may not have photoshop installed correctly
I'm trying to write code that will take data from an excel spreadsheet and fit it into certain layers in a psd file.Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
from photoshop import Session
import os


def update_psd_with_excel_data(excel_path, psd_template_path, output_dir):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        brand = row['Brand']
        name = row['Name']
        price = row['Price']
        image_path = row['Image']

        with Session(psd_template_path, action="open") as ps:
            doc = ps.app.activeDocument

            update_text_layer(doc, 'brand', brand)
            update_text_layer(doc, 'name', name)
            update_text_layer(doc, 'price', price)

            update_image_layer(doc, 'product_image', r'%s' % image_path)

            output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f"{name}.jpg")
            save_as_jpg(doc, output_path, ps)


def update_text_layer(doc, layer_name, text):
    layer = doc.artLayers[layer_name]
    if layer.kind == 2:  # ps.LayerKind.TextLayer
        text_item = layer.textItem
        text_item.contents = text


def update_image_layer(doc, layer_name, image_path):
    layer = doc.artLayers[layer_name]
    if layer.kind == 1:  # ps.LayerKind.SmartObjectLayer
        layer.smartObject.updateContents(image_path)


def save_as_jpg(doc, output_path, ps, quality=12):
    jpg_options = ps.JPEGSaveOptions()
    jpg_options.quality = quality

    jpg_file = ps.File(output_path)
    doc.saveAs(jpg_file, jpg_options, asCopy=True)


excel_path = r'C:\Users\Arsen\Desktop\test.xlsx'
psd_template_path = r'C:\Users\Arsen\Desktop\phtsjjjf.psd'
output_dir = r'C:\Users\Arsen\Desktop'

update_psd_with_excel_data(excel_path, psd_template_path, output_dir)


I have photoshop on my laptop. This code is in a python file.
I can't even test the functionality of the code, because it immediately gives me an error when I run it:
photoshop.api.errors.PhotoshopPythonAPIError: Please check if you have Photoshop installed correctly.
I tried to run photoshop first, and then the code; I added the photoshop location to the path variable, but it didn't work
